# Reference request : Besov spaces on ubounded domains

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, besov-spaces

As I am relatively new to these matters, I would like to know if you could provide me a reference for Besov spaces on unbounded domains, because when I checked the first tome of Triebel's Theory of Function Spaces, I only found the case of a smooth bounded set aside of whole or half space (in Bergh's Interpoation spaces, there is no mention neither of these spaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hormander: The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators II, 1983, page 13 ff.

These spaces are $B_{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)\cap \mathcal E'(X)$, where $X$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

O.V Besov, V.P Il'in, S.M Nikolskii. *Integral Representations of Functions and  Embedding Theorems*. Most of results are stated for arbitrary domains $G\subset \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew, I didn't accept your answer because I can only accept one, but I really appreciate the extra reference. I didn't know Besov himself wrote about the subject; sometimes in Analysis, there are pioneers who don't write about their own work, e.g. Calderón.

Answer (score 1):

The following papers may help:

- "Besov Spaces on Domains in $\mathbb{R}^d$" by R. Devore and R. Sharpley

This paper is for Besov spaces $B^{\alpha}_{q}(L_p(\Omega)),~p,q,\alpha \in (0,\infty )$ on domains $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1993-335-02/S0002-9947-1993-1152321-6/S0002-9947-1993-1152321-6.pdf

- "Elliptic and parabolic problems in unbounded domains" by Patrick Guidotti

This examines general existence and regularity results in Besov spaces (specifically, on unbounded domains $\mathbb{R}^n\times\Omega$).

http://www.math.uci.edu/~gpatrick/source/papers/G041.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Simpson, this is a good complementary reference that you added here, as Hörmander's treatment of the subject does not include the Besov spaces of three parameters.

Comment: No problem. I am quite interested in Besov spaces.